# Getting started with Heroku- git push heroku master hangs indefinitely?

Tags: python, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have been following the "Getting Started With Python on Heroku" tutorial located [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python) and everything works as expected. However, when I try to execute the final 'git push heroku master' command, nothing happens. There is no output, it just hangs.

My heroku remote shows up when I do 'git remote -v', my Procfile and requirements.txt are in place, and I have no issues pushing to Github from my terminal.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Did you solve yours?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created an app `heroku create <appname>`?

Do you have git setup on your terminal/command line?

Maybe try re-installing Heroku.

You don't give too much info, so this is all I can help with for now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created a few apps using the heroku create command, git is running (version 1.7.12.4), and I tried re-installing Heroku with no luck.

Comment: I had same problem. But I had used only heroku create. But using with appname like heroku create myapp solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem while going through the same tutorial. The solution for me was to change the firewall settings on my gateway/router.